# How to get first IN and last Out of Swipe data for Night shift employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get First in and Last out in multiple records with night shift:

We have Date, Time, EmpId, InOut,  Shift_Start_Time and Shift_End_Time of an employee.

Need your help to write a sql for these conditions:

1.Consider the records which Time is falling between Shift_Start_Time and Shift_End_Time. If the In/Out time is outside the shift_start & Shift_End time, ignore them.
 Ex:Shift_Start_Time is 18:00:00 and Shift_End_Time is 07:00:00. If my In time is before 18:00 or Out time is after 07:00, no need to consider.

2. Take first IN and Last OUT between Shift_Start and Shift_End time window.
   Note:Here Date will change for night shift. Ex: First IN time is 18:30 on 03/04/2020 and OUT time is 06:30 on 03/05/2020
3. If it is day shift, simply take first IN and last OUT time of an emp and this time should be between Shift_Start and Shift_End time.

My current sql:

```
*SELECT
   CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, convert(varchar(12), R.[date], 1), 103), 120) as date,
   R.[Time],
   substring(R.[Empid], 3, 7) as EmpID,
   R.[InOut],
   P.[Shift_Start_Time],
   P.[Shift_End_Time] 
FROM
   [dbo].[India_Swipe_Details] R 
   Left join
      [India_Employee_Ref] P 
      on substring(R.[Empid], 3, 7) = P.[India_ID] 
Where
   remark = 'Successful' 
   and type like 'Permanent%' 
   and gate in 
   (
      'B-1a Main Door 1',
      'B-1a Main Door 2',
      'B-1a North Fire Exit',
      'B-1a South Fire Exit',
      'Main Entry',
      'North Service Exit',
      'Secondary Entry',
      'South Fire Exit',
      'B5 Reception',
      'Opal Room(ops)',
      'Operation Floor(biometricacc.door)',
      'South Service Exit',
      'XOME_RECEPTION_ENTRY',
      'XOME_SERVICE_LIFT'
   )
   ---and substring(R.[Empid],3,7)=550270
   ---and (time >=[shift_start_time] or time <=[shift_End_time] )
order by
   [date],
   [time]*
```

Sample Data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLrRA.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the test data as text, we cant use it as image. Please

Comment: Sample Data     
date Time EmpID InOut Shift_Start_Time Shift_End_Time
1/15/2020 17:45:28 AM 550270 In 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/15/2020 19:17:01 AM 550270 out 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/15/2020 21:42:16 AM 550270 In 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/16/2020 1:16:59 550270 Out 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/16/2020 6:30:40 550270 out 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/16/2020 6:59:45 550271 In 6:00:00 17:00:00
1/16/2020 11:45:14 550271 out 6:00:00 17:00:00
1/16/2020 13:44:22 PM 550271 In 6:00:00 17:00:00
1/16/2020 16:44:22 PM 550271 Out 6:00:00 17:00:00
1/16/2020 17:44:22 PM 550271 In 6:00:00 17:00:00

Comment: Output:     
date Time EmpID InOut Shift_Start_Time Shift_End_Time
1/15/2020 21:42:16 AM 550270 In 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/16/2020 6:30:40 550270 out 18:00:00 7:00:00
1/16/2020 6:59:45 550271 In 6:00:00 17:00:00
1/16/2020 16:44:22 PM 550271 Out 6:00:00 17:00:00

Comment: @Zip Is that sample data and expected data fine?

Comment: Filter the data first to remove the records to be ignored, then use MIN and MAX with GROUP BY to retrieve the relevant datetimes.

Comment: how can we get for night shift?

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't use images for sample data. Instead, use formatted text with DDL+DML statements, so that whomever answers your question can copy the sample data into a test environment and check the answer before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I got that problem before:

I come up with for example you have a record like this:

```
ID         DATE_IN                 DATE_OUT                FIRST_IN_ID
24     03-05-2020 08:01:00        
25                           03-06-2020 01:01:00               24
```

This field  `FIRST_IN_ID`    will identify which  `ID` of `IN` should be the partner of your `OUT`. To That way you can easily got the query of your data.

Just want to help you.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for checking this. But i need in the same output format which i provided in this post

Comment: the first_in_id is very helpful to this particular problem.. think about it

Comment: I need the output like this since this format is required to load in application:

Comment: are you working to an existing database or a new database?

Comment: Existing database.

Comment: This gonna be a huge script you have to create if you cannot modify your table and add the first_in_id field